# WGCNA error: Length of colors vector not compatible with number of objects in 'order'

Tags: r, bioconductor, wgcna

```r
plotDendroAndColors(bwnet$dendrograms[[1]], cbind(bwnet$unmergedColors, bwnet$colors),
                    c("unmerged", "merged"),
                    dendroLabels = FALSE,
                    addGuide = TRUE,
                    hang= 0.03,
                    guideHang = 0.05)
```

I am getting the following error. colrs modules are not coming in  dendrogram graph. I am using 4gb ram laptop. is this problem because of laptop or my mistake in understanding code.

```r
Error in .plotOrderedColorSubplot(order = order, colors = colors,
rowLabels = rowLabels, : Length of colors vector not compatible with
number of objects in 'order'. madam getting this error.
```

My total genes are 15456. Under blockwisemodule I chose 5000

Comment: Welcome to the site. Firstly, what data set is this? Weighted correlation network analysis (WGCNA) whilst published in a bioinformatics journal could be applied to any data set, i.e. not necessarily a biological data set. The context of this question is quite important. WGCNA (2008) is not widely used and there could be alternative approaches.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the code in [WGCNA tutorial](https://horvath.genetics.ucla.edu/html/CoexpressionNetwork/Rpackages/WGCNA/Tutorials/index.html) section 2c. Since the analysis ran in blockwise manner, you need to plot the dendrograms for each block separately and subset the module colors to each block. The example code is in the tutorial.